# Razor-pay failed to show input fields on Lollipop and marshmallow Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, razorpay

Configuration AndroidApp -

- com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.13 minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 29
  com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3

on Lollipop and marshmallow 
it creating crash to solve that I override config

```
       public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <=23 && (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode == this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode)) {
               return;
           }
           super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
       }
```

**it solved my crash but when razorpay webview open that hide inputfields**

[image]

Comment: Now they solve this issue , Thanks razorpay

Comment: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-android-sample-app/releases solved release links